# Refit Net core AddRefitClient Read Response Header

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, refit, httpclientfactory

I need help with the below code for a WPF .net core 3.1 app which uses Refit for handing REST APIs. I am trying to get the value of the AuthToken from the response header. But I can't find a property holds the value of the AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter.

I do see some bugs related to this issue - https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/689. It is claimed to have been fixed in the .net core 3.1 version. But I haven't been able to retrieve the response header yet.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRefitClient<IService>(new RefitSettings()
            {
                AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult("AuthToken")
            })
            .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new 
             Uri(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig:GatewayService").Value));
        }
```

**IService.cs**
The Interface IService has been defined as follows:

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [Post("/v1/Authtoken/")]
        public Task<string> Authenticate([Body] Authenticate payload);
    }
```

I am Injecting IService in my ViewModel (WPF) and trying to get the the value of the "AuthToken" header which should have been set.

**Viewmodel**

```
    public class SomeViewModel: ISomeViewModel
    {
        public SomeViewModel(IService service)
        {
            this.Service = service;
        }

        public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> Somemethod()
        {
            var authResponse = await Service.Authenticate(authPayload);

            .......
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the response header. The return type of the service has to be changed to System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [Post("/v1/Authtoken/")]
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authenticate([Body] Authenticate payload);
    }
```

Created an extension method which looks up the response headers to get the "AuthToken" value.

```
public static class RefitExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<string>GetAuthToken(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> task)
        {
            var response = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            string authToken = response.Headers.GetValues("AuthToken").FirstOrDefault();
            return await Task.FromResult(authToken);
        }
    }
```

In the view model, I got the authtoken value with the following statement.

```
var authToken = await Service.Authenticate(authPayload).GetAuthToken();
```